# Class and class extension (category) in the same header file

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I look around the Cocoa Touch API, I can find some classes declared along with categories in the same header file, e.g.

```
@interface NSArray : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding, NSFastEnumeration>

@property (readonly) NSUInteger count;
// and some other properties

@end

@interface NSArray (NSExtendedArray)

@property (readonly, copy) NSString *description;
// and some other properties

@end
```

Now I am trying to do the same thing with my class, like as follow:

```
@interface ARCTextbook : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger ID;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;

@end

@interface ARCTextbook (Student)

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger studentID;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isUsed) BOOL used; // Used by a student?

@end
```

However, when I tried to access `studentID` or `used` property, I got an unrecognized selector error. Am I missing anything?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Associated Objects, you can refer documentation in below:

http://www.davidhamrick.com/2012/02/12/Adding-Properties-to-an-Objective-C-Category.html

[How to store not id type variable use a objc_getAssociatedObject/objc_setAssociatedObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890414/how-to-store-not-id-type-variable-use-a-objc-getassociatedobject-objc-setassocia)

ARCTextbook.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ARCTextbook : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger ID;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@end

@interface ARCTextbook (Student)

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger studentID;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isUsed) BOOL used; // Used by a student?

@end
```

ARCTextbook.m

```
#import "ARCTextbook.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation ARCTextbook

@end

static NSString *kStudentID = @"kStudentID";
static NSString *kUsed = @"kUsed";

@implementation ARCTextbook (Student)
@dynamic studentID;
@dynamic used;

- (void)setStudentID:(NSInteger)aStudentID {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void *)(kStudentID), @(aStudentID), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSInteger)studentID {
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void *)(kStudentID)) integerValue];
}

- (void)setUsed:(BOOL)aUsed {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void *)(kUsed), @(aUsed), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (BOOL)isUsed {
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void *)(kUsed)) boolValue];
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ARCTextbook.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    ARCTextbook *t = [[ARCTextbook alloc] init];
    t.studentID = 2;
    t.used = YES;

}

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the code? I encountered the unrecognized selector error during runtime.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. I guess there's no way to get around this but to use associated object !